# Glassmapper causing high CPU usage on Sitecore publishing in two CD servers

Tags: glass-mapper

Sitecore support has suggested that following code has an issue after analyzing the `w3wp` process dumps.

The `Glass.Mapper.IoC.AbstractConfigFactory` class has many lock syntax. This locked variable may be occupied by an unknown thread, but 82 threads with the same stack trace are waiting for this to be resolved. It looks related to the CPU spike.

Could you please help me in this issue?

> Glass.Mapper.IoC.AbstractConfigFactory`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].GetItems()+53 
>   Glass.Mapper.AbstractService..ctor(Glass.Mapper.Context)+55 
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService..ctor(Sitecore.Data.Database, System.String)+37 
>   MyDomain.Extensions.ItemExtensions.Cast[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]](Sitecore.Data.Items.Item, Boolean, Boolean)+a6 
>   DynamicClass.lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase, System.Object[])+4f 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2)+f2

Comment: Can you share how your environment is setup? VS Version, Glass Mapper Version, Sitecore version. Also there are diagnostics you can add to your code to see where the bottleneck could be. http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/Diagnostics

Comment: We need to see how your models are set up as well, and any code which is calling those models (e.g. Controllers). It's difficult to diagnose from just the stacktrace since it's very much an implementation specific issue.

Comment: We are using VS Version 2017, GlassMapper version 4.4.0.199 and Sitecore version 8.1 With Update 1.

Comment: based on this question and another about locking issues in this class we are looking to move locks in the next release. There is currently a beta package that contains this change. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc/4.4.1.329-beta

Comment: Thanks Michael Edwards. I will deploy latest Glass.Mapper.Sc 4.5.0.4 and verify.

Comment: I have updated the latest Glass.Mapper.Sc still seeing the high CPU usage.

Comment: I am using following code to cast item, is this correct way to do, please let me know

`var service = new SitecoreService(item.Database);
 return service.Cast<T>(item, isLazy, inferType);`